# Error processRemote Type mismatch with ALAudioDevice on Pepper

Tags: python, nao-robot, pepper, choregraphe

I want to record the sound of the Pepper microphone and stream it to a server.
I followed the code on [the naoqi documentation](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-4/dev/python/examples/audio/audio_soundprocessing.html) and adapted it for a **Choregraphe python box**.

When I launch the program, I've got the following error :

```
[ERROR] ALAudioDeviceClient :threadReader:0 Error on processRemote, stopping thread:    AudioModule::processRemote  Type mismatch
```

Here's my code :

```
import qi

class AudioModule(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(AudioModule, self).__init__()
        self.moduleName = "AudioModule"
        try :
            self.ALAudioDevice = ALProxy("ALAudioDevice")
        except Exception, e:
            self.logger.error("Error when creating proxy on ALAudioDevice:")
            self.logger.error(e)

    def begin_stream(self):
        self.ALAudioDevice.setClientPreferences(self.moduleName, 16000, 3, 0)
        self.ALAudioDevice.subscribe(self.moduleName)

    def end_stream(self):
        self.ALAudioDevice.unsubscribe(self.moduleName)

    def processRemote( self, nbOfChannels, samplesByChannel, altimestamp, buffer ):
        nbOfChannels = nbOfChannels
        #mylogger = qi.Logger("data")
        #mylogger.info("It works ! " + nbOfChannels)

class MyClass(GeneratedClass):
    def __init__(self):
        GeneratedClass.__init__(self, False)
        self.audio = AudioModule()

    def onLoad(self):
        self.serviceId = self.session().registerService("AudioModule", self.audio)
        pass

    def onUnload(self):
        if self.serviceId != -1:
            self.session().unregisterService(self.serviceId)
            self.serviceId = -1
        pass

    def onInput_onStart(self):
        self.audio.begin_stream()

    def onInput_onStop(self):
        self.audio.end_stream()
```

The structure of the processRemote function is the same as the example so why do I get a Type mismatch error ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: I did a few tests with this a while ago, with the parameters setClientPreferences: 48000,0,0... would you mind trying with those? don't know if that would help.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I've got the same error with those parameters :(
I gave up the implementation on a Choregraphe box and writed those functions on a pure python program, it works without any problem...
It seems that the audio recording using processRemote is not compatible with Choregraphe :/

Answer (score 1):

Quite often "type mismatch" or "conversion" errors can come from the way you get your naoqi module. Here you get it the "old" (naoqi v.1) way :

```
self.ALAudioDevice = ALProxy("ALAudioDevice")
```

Which can generate conversion errors. Can you try to get it the new way, via the session :

```
self.ALAudioDevice = self.session().service("ALAudioDevice")
```

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that your ALAudioDevice object doesn't have a "logger" member - you could just pass that one to your constructor (and also use it instead of the "mylogger" you use later on).

But the problem is probably coming from your

```
"It works ! " + nbOfChannels
```

... because you're trying to add a string and an integer, which Python doesn't like; do something like

```
"It works ! %i" % nbOfChannels
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
The two lines on the processRemote function are just here for the example.
If I replace them with nbOfChannels = nbOfChannels, the same error is still there.